# How can I test a lightbox-driven UI in an automated fashion?

Tags: jquery, drupal, lightbox, automated-tests

I am a tester and I use crossbrowsertesting.com (not a plug; just the site I signed up for) and the developers building the web app (on a Drupal platform) used lightbox to access some features. So, the flow would be that you get to mysite.com/home and then click on a div which has no URL per se, and instead a lightbox effect dims the page and a modal window appears within mysite.com/home with the additional content.

I'd like to see what that additional content looks like in the different browsers I need to test, but I don't see a specific URL that I can plug into crossbrowsertesting.com in order to run the automated screenshot test.

Anyone have experience on grabbing automated screenshots of something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following website allows you to take screenshots of a lot of different browsers for free.
http://browsershots.org/

Make sure that you fill in an URL that starts the lightbox automatically, if not so you would just see the page without the lightbox.

Choose one of the browsers that will support JQuery.

Good luck testing!

Comment: Thanks! We actually figured out that, indeed, the secret sauce was that we needed to add a URL parameter in order to get the lightbox element to show up. browsershots.org is a great site, but we've graduated to crossbrowsertesting.com for $29.99/mo... well worth it... it's amazing.